# UIImage: imageNamed crash

Tags: uiimage

I am having truble while using [UIImage imageNamed:] method
It appeares that crash occured when launching app from killed state and getting an resource image.
All my images are stored in bundle and no issue with background thread.
Following is crash log

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
19 UIKit                          0x186739714 +[UIImage imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:] + 380
20 UIKit                          0x18658cc8c +[UIImage imageNamed:] + 124

This happens on 
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];